# ASP.Net Core, Create Model with Complex Data Type Property

Tags: asp.net-core

In Asp.Net Core, I have created the below models:

```
[Keyless]
public class NameSet
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public NameSet Name { get; set; }
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

In ApplicationDbContext class:

```
public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
```

Now, I want the table as like below in my database:

| Id | FirstName | MiddleName | LastName | Mobile | Email | IsActive |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

When I am trying the above, it is giving me an error during the add-migration:

```
Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation 'Customer.Name' of type 'NameSet'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.
```

**Please suggest, how could I mature my "CustomerModel" with the "NameSet" property so I could do it so.**

Comment: why you dont put the FirstName, MiddleName, LastName properties in Customer Class?

Comment: Could you please share your dbcontext class?

Comment: I am just trying only one:

        public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }

Comment: any specific reason for trying with one? @anand

Comment: I want to create some defined structures eg. AddressSet (HouseNo, Street, City, State, Zip), Duration (Value, Period), Size(Value, Measurement), and so on.

Comment: I am developing a framework that has some defined terminologies. It could be an AddressSet, DurationSet, SizeSet, and so forth. You could say, these are non-premtive datatypes.

Comment: or you can set NameSet as derived data type of those three fields

Comment: Like public string Name { get => $"{this.FirstName} {this.MiddleName} {this.LastName}"; private set; }

Comment: Yes, the further things will be the same as you shared

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227998/discussion-between-fahim-abrar-and-anand).

Comment: sure, I'm connecting...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`OwnsOne`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities). The code below is tested with EF Core 3.1.11.

Here's a complete example which will create exactly the table you want:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

namespace MyConsoleApp
{
    class Program : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<MyDbContext>
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }

        public MyDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
        {
            var configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);

            IConfigurationRoot configuration = configurationBuilder.Build();
            string connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("Storage");

            DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDbContext> optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDbContext>()
                .UseSqlServer(connectionString);

            return new MyDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
        }
    }

    public class MyDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options) : base(options) { }
        public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
            builder.Entity<Customer>().OwnsOne(p => p.Name, sa =>
            {
                sa.Property(p => p.FirstName).HasColumnName("FirstName");
                sa.Property(p => p.LastName).HasColumnName("LastName");
                sa.Property(p => p.MiddleName).HasColumnName("MiddleName");
            });
        }

    }

    public class NameSet
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string MiddleName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }

    public class Customer
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public NameSet Name { get; set; }
        public string Mobile { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Generated SQL from the migration will look something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Customers](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [FirstName] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [MiddleName] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [LastName] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Mobile] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Email] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [IsActive] [bit] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Customers] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

And the migration itself will look like this:

```
    migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
        name: "Customers",
        columns: table => new
        {
            Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
            FirstName = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
            MiddleName = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
            LastName = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
            Mobile = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
            Email = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
            IsActive = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false)
        },
        constraints: table =>
        {
            table.PrimaryKey("PK_Customers", x => x.Id);
        });
```

Comment: Thanks, I added the [Owned] attribute at the class level and got the desired result.

Comment: I am using ASP.NET Core 5.0 (net5.0)